# Enable "Display labels from the next field in the same column (compact form)

Tags: excel, vba, row, field, setting

Is there a way to enable the option "Display labels from the next field in the same column (compact form) in VBA?

[image: img1]

This only enables the "Show item labels in outline form"

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Name of pivot table").PivotFields("Name of pivot field").LayoutForm = xlOutline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Name of pivot table").PivotFields("Name of pivot field").LayoutCompactRow = True
```